# Number of cliques in a graph

Tags: graphs, reference-request, clique

I think the number of cliques in a graph is generally exponential in the of vertices of that graph. Does anyone know any reference for that?

Comment: I would recommend reading this: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602191

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried counting the number of cliques in the complete graph on $n$ vertices, as a function of $n$?

Comment: This is an extremely straightforward observation (consider @D.W.'s suggestion) and a citation isn't required. Sure, you could probably find somebody who's published this fact but giving them a citation would look silly and they certainly won't have been the first person to make the observation.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks, for a complete graph of $n$ vertices, I think the number of cliques is $n \choose 1$ + $n \choose 2$ + $\ldots$ + $n \choose n$ = $2^n$. Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you mean the number of *maximal cliques*, as the number of cliques of a complete graph is trivially $2^n$ (any subset of the vertices forms a clique).

For the number of maximal cliques, take the complement of a disjoint union of triangles.  Since the number of *maximal independent sets* is exactly the same (in the complement), you can count the number of maximal independent set in a graph that is a disjoint union of triangles.  This number is $3^{n/3}$ (Moon and Moser, 1965).

See also: [The number of cliques in a graph: the Moon and Moser 1965 result](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8390).